# How to read columns header in tab delimited text file C#

Tags: c#

I have a file upload control for user to upload a tab delimited file, and I want to read only the headers of each column after uploading the file, I am expecting the user to upload a file with these headers in each columns

```
Procedure-Code  Waiting-Days    Group-ID
```

I want to make sure that the file the user uploaded has the exact columns header as mentioned above, if the user uploads something like this

```
Procedure       Waiting         Group
123             5               54321
123             5               54321
123             5               54321
123             5               54321
123             5               54321
```

I want to go through that headers and check if its the same with what I want, if its not, it should return an error message saying invalid columns header....

This is my code for uploading the file, but I don't know the next step to take

```
string FileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadFile.PostedFile.FileName);
        string FilePath = Server.MapPath("~/uploads/Endorsement/" + FileName);
        uploadFile.SaveAs(FilePath);

        StreamReader streamreader = new StreamReader(FilePath);
        char[] delimiter = new char[] { '\t' };
        string[] columnheaders = streamreader.ReadLine().Split(delimiter);
```

Comment: There are libraries available to do all this for you because it is more difficult to do it right than it seems  Look at CSVHelper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After minutes of thinking I realize I was only missing foreach statement to perform the exact thing I want, in case someone else run into similar problem like this, this is how I was able to solve mine

```
string FileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadFile.PostedFile.FileName);
        string FilePath = Server.MapPath("~/uploads/Endorsement/" + FileName);
        uploadFile.SaveAs(FilePath);

        StreamReader streamreader = new StreamReader(FilePath);
        char[] delimiter = new char[] { '\t' };
        string[] columnheaders = streamreader.ReadLine().Split(delimiter);

        foreach (string columnheader in columnheaders)
        {
            if (columnheader.Contains("Procedure Code") || columnheader.Contains("Waiting Days") || columnheader.Contains("Group ID"))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                if ((File.Exists(FilePath)))
                {
                    lblError.Text = "Invalid Columns Provided";
                }
            }
        }
```